# sorting a list of tuple by second element but if the second element of mutiple tuple matches then sort using the first element

Tags: python, c++, list, sorting, tuples

Given a list of tuples where first and second elements are integer. Sort them using the second element but if the second element matches sort them using first element. Basically, I am trying to convert `c++` `pair<int, int>` type comparison to python code. This is the `c++` version.

```
bool cmp(const pair<int,int>& a, const pair<int,int>& b)
{
    if(a.second != b.second) return a.second < b.second;
    return a.first < b.first;
}

int main() {
   //some code here

   sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);

   //some code here

   return 0;
}
```

this code produces,

`input: [(2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 5), (8, 10), (6, 9)]`

`output: [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 6), (6, 9), (8, 10)]`

I tried to convert that code in `python`

```
sil = [(2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 5), (8, 10), (6, 9)]

sil.sort(key = lambda y : y[1])
```

But sadly this only produces `output: [(2, 5), (1, 5), (3, 6), (6, 9), (8, 10)]`. Clearly, (1, 5) should come before (2, 5) but it didn't happen.

My question is how to implement this in `python` so the output should be `[(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 6), (6, 9), (8, 10)]`

Comment: the c++ version could use `return std::pair<int,int>{a.second,a.first} < std::pair<int,int>{b.second,b.first};`. I suppose similar is possible in python

Comment: That can be shortened, with less chance for dumb errors to this: `bool cmp(const pair<int,int>& a, const pair<int,int>& b) { return std::tie(a.second, a.first) < std::tie(b.second, b.first); }`.  It is also more scalable if later you decide there are more than two members to compare in a waterfall fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify both the elements in the `key` -

```py
inp = [(2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 5), (8, 10), (6, 9)]
sorted(inp, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 6), (6, 9), (8, 10)]
```

Comment: So is this implies, first try to compare second element but if they match compare fist element?

Comment: @altair00 Yes. In python, tuples are compared using the standard lexicographical comparison: compare first element, and if equal, compare second element, etc. Here `lambda x: (x[1], x[0])` is responsible for swapping the first and second element.